# CIR calculation from SDR data: RTL-SDR, bladeRF

Tags: python, cross-correlation, software-defined-radio

We’re developing a prototype using bladeRF and various Python scripts for processing IQ samples.

The system works mainly around 2.4 GHz frequencies: Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

One of the needed functions is about CIR (Channel Impulse Response) estimation for the collected IQ samples on a specific frequency.

Question - are there any functions in SciPy, NumPy or any other Python modules for CIR calculations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with which method do you plan to estimate the CIR, and to what "extent", i.e., bandwidth, estimation variance? Saying "I want the CIR" kind of requires you to define the channel you care about".